# Eloquent query to search over two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am struggling with the following query, using Eloquent in Laravel 5.6.

I need to return all issues that have a `tag_id` of `5` assigned to them, where the `project_id` and `item_id` from the issues table matches the `project_id` and `issue_id` from my pivot table.

**issues table:**

[image]

**issues_tags pivot table:**

[image]

I have tried the following code, but it returns all issues from the issue table, however the expectation is 3 results.

**Expected results**

The results returned from the `issues` table should be ID 1, 4 and 5.

```
$issues = Issue::join('issues_tags', 'issues_tags.project_id', 'issues_tags.issue_id')->where('issues_tags.tag_id', 5)->select('issues.*')->get();
```

Comment: try `leftJoin` instead of `join`

Comment: Produces the same result.

Comment: You can use `toSql` or `getQueryLog` method to see SQL query if that looks ok?

Comment: `$issues = Issue::join('issues_tags', 'issues.project_id', 'issues_tags.project_id')->join('issues_tags', 'issues.item_id', 'issues_tags.issue_id')->where('issues_tags.tag_id', 5)->select('issues.*')->get();`

Comment: can you show us the expected results ?

Comment: @tech2017 This returns: `Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'issues_tags' (SQL: select `issues`.* from `issues` inner join `issues_tags` on `issues`.`project_id` = `issues_tags`.`project_id` inner join `issues_tags` on `issues`.`item_id` = `issues_tags`.`issue_id` where `issues_tags`.`tag_id` = 5)`

Comment: I updated the question with expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the issues table instead of issues_tags on the join. A left join will also help reduce the results. Since you're joining on two different keys, you have to use a closure.

```
$issues = Issue::leftJoin('issues_tags', function($join) {
    $join->on('issues.project_id', '=', 'issues_tags.project_id');
    $join->on('issues.item_id', '=', 'issues_tags.issue_id');
})
->where('issues_tags.tag_id', 5)->select('issues.*')->get();
```

If the table is really supposed to match on project_id->project_id and issues.id -> issues_tags.issues_id, you can modify the 2nd join clause.

Comment: The explanation makes sense. I fixed a couple of issues in your code related to missing quotes and using a singular `issues_tags.issue_id ` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: `issues_tags.issues_id` just remove `s` , should be  `issue_id`. now its work perfect